# SQL replace for given pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a text like following on a database field (SQL Server 2000)

`"Led sledding leding led go led"`

I want SQL Command to replace the word `led` to `LED`, But it shouldn't change words like "sledding" / "leding"

There are 15,000 records with similar text. Need to apply this for all of them.

I have tried following but it takes more than 24 hours. (With in a cursor)

```
update rprd 
set dsc = replace(dsc, 'led ', 'LED ')
where dsc not like 'LED %' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as
and dsc like 'led %'

update rprd 
set dsc = replace(dsc, ' led ', ' LED ')
where dsc not like '% LED %' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as
and dsc like '% led %'

update rprd 
set dsc = replace(dsc, ' led', ' LED')
where dsc not like '% LED' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as
and dsc like '% led'
```

Please suggest me a faster and simple way of doing this.

Comment: Which database server are you using? The syntax tends to vary by vendor.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't (edit: didn't *initially*) specify which database you are using.

Most database vendors have a function with general syntax like, or very close to `REPLACE( source-string, from-string, to-string )`, but the syntax will vary in terms of what kinds of wildcards you can use or whether you can use regular expressions, and case-sensitivity differs among vendors with regard to object names and string *lookups*. However, replacing a string with a string of a specific case will work with every vendor.

For your first pass, you might try something as simple as replacing `' led '` (led with a space on either side of it), like this:

`REPLACE( somefield, ' led ', ' LED ' )`

TSQL does support some modestly advanced wildcard searches:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I take it, you just need to correct some existing data once, and you dont need a solution to use constantly.

so why dont you run a few queries that solve your problem easily and quickly,

```
UPDATE table SET field=regexp_replace(field, '^led ', 'LED ');
UPDATE table SET field=regexp_replace(field, ' led$', ' LED');
UPDATE table SET field=regexp_replace(field, ' led ', ' LED ');
```

make sure to check your db docs on correct syntax of your functions

Comment: SQL Server 2005 didn't support regular expressions.